# How to run the exe from a different folder using ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#

I have a program under c:\windows\system32\csexport.exe . If I open a cmd window, and run the command, it works fine and generate an output file under c:\windows\system32\csexport

However, if I use File.Exists(file), it will always return false because of some security reason. So, I open a cmd window, then go to c:\tmp folder, then run the csexport.exe with full path, then it will output the file in c:\tmp .

So I try to do this in C#. Here is the code

```
public ProcessResult RunProcess(string fileName, string arguments, string workingDirectory)
{
    var processResult = new ProcessResult();
    // prep process
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName, arguments)
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
        , WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
    };
    // start process  
    using (var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
    {   // pass process data
        process.StartInfo = psi;
        process.Start();
        processResult.Data = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();
        processResult.ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
    }
    return processResult;
}
```

But, how can I set it to run from c:\tmp ?

---

I did more test, and had weird result:

I set UseShellExecute = false, and then set workingDirectory = "C:\tmp", the filename with full path. when run it, it shows this error:

The following exception occurred: System.InvalidOperationException: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at ENow.Os.Utilities.ProcessWrapper.RunProcess(String fileName, String arguments, String workingDirectory)
   ...

But, UseShellExecute  is set as false already.

Comment: That's exactly what `WorkingDirectory` means.

Comment: Did you set `WorkingDirectory` to `C:\tmp`?

Comment: does that mean the exe has to be in workingDirectory? I check the doc here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx , maybe I misunderstood it. Let me check. thanks

Comment: The answer is in the [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page: "When UseShellExecute is true, the working directory of the application that starts the executable is also the working directory of the executable". With `UseShellExecute=true` you should be able to change your current processes `CurrentDirectory` then launch your other one and it willl inherit it. Putting `Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\tmp\";` directly above `process.Start()` should work.

Comment: Don't use UseShellExecute=true, you need to use false. You also need to provide the FULL path to the executable. Then you can set workingDirectory to where you like. Also maybe the executable has an argument to control the output file directory.